# Store specific values from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Received: from mout.perfora.net ([74.208.4.194]:64110)
            [1] => Received: from localhost (cpe-142-255-38-220.nyc.res.rr.com [142.255.38.220])
            [2] => From: xxxxx <phoneleash@gearandroid.com>
            [3] => To: 1v5z9hrt5z@thegrouptextshow.com
            [4] => Message-ID: <1113754192.698.1364695577947.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
            [5] => References: <M38aa3cba44b8.+@gearandroid.com>
            [6] => Subject: Re: SMS: +
            [7] => MIME-Version: 1.0
            [8] => Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
            [9] => X-PhoneLeash: <M38aa3cba44b8.+@gearandroid.com>
            [10] => Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 22:06:17 -0400
            [11] => X-Provags-ID: V02:K0:leU7uup/etOXU8iaKYpIvO81rtv82ALEDU7D1ZsEeqw
            [12] => Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
            [13] => Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
            [14] => Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
            [15] => [Sent: 10:06 PM 03/30/2013]
            [16] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [17] => Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
            [18] => <HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">C TN<br>---<br>Add // to the end of your reply<br>[Sent: 10:06 PM 03/30/2013]<hr><table style="margin: auto;"><tr><td><a href=https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.facebook.com/phoneleash><img src="http://gearandroid.com/pics/fbshare.png"></a></td><font face="helvetica"><td><a href=https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.facebook.com/phoneleash>Enjoy PhoneLeash? Let your FB friends know!</a></td></font></tr></table><br></BODY></HTML>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Received
            [1] => Received
            [2] => From
            [3] => To
            [4] => Message-ID
            [5] => References
            [6] => Subject: Re: SMS
            [7] => MIME-Version
            [8] => Content-Type
            [9] => X-PhoneLeash
            [10] => Date
            [11] => X-Provags-ID
            [12] => Content-Type
            [13] => Content-Type
            [14] => Content-Transfer-Encoding
            [15] => [Sent
            [16] => Content-Type
            [17] => Content-Transfer-Encoding
            [18] => <HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">C TN<br>---<br>Add // to the end of your reply<br>[Sent: 10:06 PM 03/30/2013]<hr><table style="margin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => from mout.perfora.net ([74.208.4.194]:64110)
            [1] => from localhost (cpe-142-255-38-220.nyc.res.rr.com [142.255.38.220])
            [2] => xxx <phoneleash@gearandroid.com>
            [3] => 1v5z9hrt5z@thegrouptextshow.com
            [4] => <1113754192.698.1364695577947.JavaMail.javamailuser@localhost>
            [5] => <M38aa3cba44b8.+@gearandroid.com>
            [6] => xxxxxxx
            [7] => 1.0
            [8] => multipart/mixed; 
            [9] => <M38aa3cba44b8.xxxxx@gearandroid.com>
            [10] => Sat, 30 Mar 2013 22:06:17 -0400
            [11] => V02:K0:leU7uup/etOXU8iaKYpIvO81rtv82ALEDU7D1ZsEeqw
            [12] => multipart/alternative; 
            [13] => text/plain; charset=UTF-8
            [14] => 7bit
            [15] => 10:06 PM 03/30/2013]
            [16] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
            [17] => 7bit
            [18] => auto;"><tr><td><a href=https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.facebook.com/phoneleash><img src="http://gearandroid.com/pics/fbshare.png"></a></td><font face="helvetica"><td><a href=https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://www.facebook.com/phoneleash>Enjoy PhoneLeash? Let your FB friends know!</a></td></font></tr></table><br></BODY></HTML>
        )

)
```

I need to be able to store the values of `[1][18]`, `[2][2]`, `[2][10]`, `[2][21]` into specific variables so that I can later cut everything in them besides that actually text and then store it as a value in MYSQL. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029897/how-to-get-values-from-multidimensional-array-in-php) sort of helped me but I need the values of only the 4 elements that I specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
require '../connect.php';
$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
preg_match_all("/(.*):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $matches);

$message    = $matches[1][18];
$message    = str_replace('<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">', '',$message);
$message    = explode('<',$message);
$message    = $message[0];
$sender     = $matches[2][2];
$sender     = explode('<',$sender); 
$sender_id  = $sender[0];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `post` (`text`,`sender`,`text_stamp`,`post_date`,`post_time`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($sender_id) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($textdate) . "','$postdate','$posttime')") or die(mysql_error() . "<--There was error processing the query");
```

Comment: Hi @user2218297, great to see you got it working in the end. One further comment I would make is looking at PDO, using prepared statements and bound queries as the mysql_* functions are now deprecated and can open you up to certain security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried storing them as so, where `$your_array` is the name of the variable holding your array above?

```
$var1 = $your_array[1][18];
$var2 = $your_array[2][2];
$var3 = $your_array[2][10];
$var4 = $your_array[2][21];
```

Bare in mind though that in the array you showed us above that there is no [2][21] value.

Comment: yes. $var1, $var2, etc. ends up acting as a pointer to the array and its element. Therefore when i try to insert the variable into the mysql DB, it inserts as ARRAY and therefore is stored as a blank field

Comment: the [2][21] only comes up when someones sends an attachment via email.

Comment: @user2218297: From the above code and the data you have posted `$var1` etc. should be the actual values from the array, not "pointer[s] to the array". If the above code results in the word "Array" then your data is in a different format to what you have posted in the question.

Comment: $email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
preg_match_all("/(.*):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $matches);

this is the code that I use to generate that array... That array that I posted is called "$matches"

Comment: an email is sent to this .php file which then does the preg match so I can obtain the data after the ':\s' such as FROM and SUBJECT etc...do you know of any other way to get that data that I need rather than using a preg match all and storing it as a multi-dim-array?

Comment: Using some form of regex, as you have done, should be OK. What does `echo $matches[2][10];` output/return?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) ) ...

but if i was to send that variable back to myself via email i would get the time stamp I am looking for. For some reason, it seems there is some type or value confusion when it comes to assigning array elements from this array to a variable. I tried sanitize then mysql_escape_string. But i still only inserted s:32'' and not the value of the variable... Something tricky is going on here

Comment: There must be some other code/process, as that doesn't make much sense based on the information/data you have posted above. `$matches[2][10]` should output something like "Sat, 30 Mar 2013 22:06:17 -0400", based on the data dump in your question. Can you add the code to your question above, including the code used to dump your array? **EDIT:** I see your edited comment now :) Yes, it should be the time stamp.

Comment: sure here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725407/insert-variable-containing-random-text-that-has-been-piped-from-email-into-mysql

Comment: `s:32` - a string of 32 chars matches the length of the timestamp, so it looks like the data is there. This is the output you might get if the array had been serialize()'d?! The actual data should follow this, like `s:32:"Sat, 30 Mar 2013 22:06:17 -0400"`?

Comment: thanks for your help man, im still not getting the value. i have found a tutorial on what I am doing though and it is helping moving things along. I will answer the question once I get this working. Ill get it done probably by 11 ish if you want to check back. You are the man though thanks for your help so far